# Abusive admins are deleting requests to reopen the question together with supplemental reasons to reopen it

Tags: support, specific-question, reopen-closed, moderators

The [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76328564/regex-in-php-to-strip-everything-except-digits-and-decimal-point-and-truncate-st) asking about a regex to truncate an alphanumeric string to two decimal places and remove non numeric characters was closed citing that the answer was provided in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342026/in-php-how-to-get-float-value-from-a-mixed-string).

All the regex in the proposed duplicate target does not answer the question. For example, if the following string Y4563.5667 is used as an input the output is 4563.5667 instead 4563.56.

My requests to reopen the question are being deleted by abusive moderators along with my supplemental explanations, even though requesting to reopen the question is permitted by the terms of service. What the is going on, is Stack Overflow now fostering incorrect answers and silencing users just like Twitter and Facebook???

Comment: The moderator's comments on your question seem to be clear and to the point. Where's the abuse here? The most abusive thing I can see is you shouting *"REOPEN THIS QUESTION AND STOP DELETING MY REQUESTS TO REOPEN IT. "* and getting into a rollback war.

Comment: I have been reviewing the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76328564/revisions) of the mentioned question, and it seems ironic and contradictory that the user is abusing the system there and complaining about abuse here.

Comment: What I find weird is instead of searching for questions about truncating a number to specific decimal digits you insisted on getting in an edit / rollback war (across multiple days). Truncating / rounding to specific digits is a commonly asked question for which it is easy to find a question on [so]

Comment: Well, personally, I think your question is unclear, because it doesn't either limit the format of the input text to something predefined or define what should happen with more complex text formats. For example, what should the output be with "2023-05-29 03:40:11Z, License: CC BY-SA 4.0", "9.95,6.432,0.3", or "po2iaw5e.ro1i7im8jjks;fl32;i.u12ma" as input strings (all of which fit your current description of your input text, but for which there's no definition of what the regex should do)?

Comment: So none of you care about the fact that the alledged answer is incorrect and is not truncating the string as asked in the question., So according to you the form is more important than the substance of the answer, that's a great way to do programming :-). Also, asking to reopen the question within the question itself if permitted by the TOS so what exactly am I abusing?

Comment: You are permitted to request reopening of your question, but it should be done in the manner the system is designed for and without being rude, regardless of how other people have behaved. However, I'm curious where you've seen an *explicit* statement in the TOS that requesting to reopen a question is permitted, and permitted in the way that you've done it (which isn't the way the system is set up to have it done). I'm only asking about where that statement is in the TOS, because I don't recall seeing any such statement in the TOS and I wonder where I missed it.

Comment: @ Makyen The example which you provided is clearly addressed by the question. The string "2023-05-29 03:40:11Z, License: CC BY-SA 4.0" should be striped of all non-numeric characters so the output should be "202305290340114.0"

Comment: @Makyen  https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions  "You can leave a comment on the question itself calling for it to be reopened."

Comment: Perhaps, but it's *very* different than the examples you provided and takes either a more complex regex or multiple steps. Your question doesn't make clear that type of input must be accounted for, and most people won't account for it in an answer, unless you make it clear in the question that it's possible as input text. What about the other examples? In particular, what should happen with "9.95,6.432,0.3" which doesn't reduce to a number with a single decimal point after removing all non-digits and non-decimal points. Note: you should *edit your question* to clarify these things.

Comment: @Jimski That's not the [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service). To be clear, I'm not and wasn't trying to pick nits on this issue. I really was wondering where you'd seen it and was surprised to have it be said to be in the Terms of Service. That it's in the Help Center vs the Terms of Service doesn't really matter. Thank you for telling me where you had seen it. I would, however, recommend that you more strongly take to mind the rest of the description in that #1 on the page you've linked.

Comment: @Makyen TOS or rules, or whatever you want to call it. My requests were permitted by stackoversflow, but were abusively deleted.  Also, if the question is not clear as you stated then the provided answer cannot address it either. Your other example "9.95,6.432,0.3" should have poduced the following output 9.95 this is because everything after the decimal point (note the singular user of "point") should have been truncated. Also, if you believe that my question was unclear then it should have been closed for a lack of clarity rather than for being answered by an answer which clearly doesn't fit

Comment: You're welcome to define it as you like, but I'd argue that the current text doesn't make it clear that what you've described here is how it should be interpreted. As I mentioned above, you *should edit your question to clarify these issues*. If you had clarified them, then it would be obvious that it is, in fact, a different question than the duplicate. As it's currently written, I could see it closed with two duplicates: the one that was used to close it and another that shows the truncation. If there are duplicates for what you're described above is something which would have to be checked.

Comment: @Jimski in fact the moderators (what I assume you mean by admins) have interacted with this meta question of yours in quite a frank manner. You've received clear and well intentioned guidance from two moderators with a third one editing this question to improve it.

Answer (score 33):

If you think your question is incorrectly closed as duplicate, you are supposed to edit it to clarify why the proposed solution(s) don't apply.

**That's the whole extent of the content you are supposed to edit into the question**.

Then you can also cast a reopen vote. Both the edit itself, if you check the "This edit resolves the original close reason..." checkbox and your reopen vote will add your question to the reopen queue, where other users will review it and decide whether to reopen it or not. **That** is the form that your "request to reopen the question" takes.

Things that won't work are:

- editing heated language to spice up the "request", [like](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76328564/2):

> Whoever marked this question as answered has no idea what he is talking about. The referenced link does not provide a regex which truncates the string to two numbers after the decimal point!!!

- editing demands to reopen the question, [like](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76328564/3):

> REOPEN THIS QUESTION.

- rolling back edits that remove that language from your post with more language like that, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76328564/5), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76328564/7):

> REOPEN THIS QUESTION AND STOP DELETING MY REQUESTS TO REOPEN IT.

After informing you about this by commenting under your post, and after revision 10, my options were to: 1) suspend your account 2) lock the post.

Unfortunately, both options aren't great because then you would be unable to edit your post *in the appropriate way*. So I left it locked for a couple days to give you time to cool off and prevent further inappropriate edits.

After I unlocked it and reminded you again about how to edit your post, you are now here claiming abuse.

The only abuse here is yours, namely, repeatedly editing demands to reopen the question (rollback war) and claiming that who closed it "has no idea what he is talking about".

Please fix your question by editing **exclusively** the reasons why the currently proposed solution doesn't work, and then let the reopen review do its course — although now that you posted in Meta, your question is going to get much more attention than usual despite how you might edit it. Still, if you do want to edit for posterity, please leave out any commentary that isn't directly related to the technical merits of your post.

Comment: Here is what I posted verbatum and you deleted it. "When an input string having three or more digits after the decimnal points is used as an input into the regex in the alledged answer the output also has three or more digits after the decimal point. For example try this input string Y673.5674 and you will get 673.5674 instead of 673.56 ."

Comment: The useful part of your edit was sandwiched between two inappropriate remarks, which you repeatedly added back into the question. It is your responsibility to edit the question with *exclusively* the technical information needed to address a potentially incorrect closure and to not engage in rollback wars.

Comment: So you deleted the substantive part instead simply delete the part whcih you deemed inappropriate. BTW which part was innapropriate, asking to reopen the question which is permitted by stackoverflow, or stating that editors didn't bother to test the answer, which was also true. Since when TRUTH is innapropriate and forbidden?

Comment: If anyone thinks someone should be suspended, please use flags, not the comments section.  I've deleted a bunch of increasingly heated comments.

Comment: @Jimski yes admittedly I did delete your entire edit to the question, including both the inappropriate remarks and the useful parts. I did so because 1) your earlier edits were unsubstantial and almost entirely inappropriate remarks 2) I repeatedly advised you about how to properly edit your question instead 3) you failed to heed those warnings. So close to the latest edits, I stopped reading the edit and only verified whether you had kept including the inappropriate parts. Why would I tolerate a rollback war after **repeatedly** advising you about what to do?

Comment: To be clear: anything that is not *directly related to the technical merits* of the question is unnecessary. Other language that directly or indirectly attacks other users is not appropriate and may range from fluff to abuse, depending on the context

Comment: Again, I think by now it is crystal clear that the answer doesn't fit the question. So either reopen the question, or if you claim that is unclear then close it for lack of clarity and please stop defending your actions and start carying about the quality of the answers.

Comment: @Jimski 1) Your question is indeed closed for lack of clarity, now 2) I intervened to stop your disruptive edits, not to assess the technical merits of question closure. I already told you how to fix your question to solve incorrect duplication, however now to have it reopened you need also to clarify it.